# Check when user returns from Settings app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I require location of the user in my application if in case the user has device location services disabled I am checking like this.

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
else if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Location Services are disabled please enable location services to enjoy nearby experience" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
    alert.tag = 103;
    [alert show];
}
```

In my alert view I am directing the user to location settings like this

```
 else if(alertView.tag == 103)
{
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {

        NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

After the user comes back from settings how to get location again

Answer (score 1):

Use `Location Delegate` method :-

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
         //Set Location Delegate
        locationManager.delegate = self;

        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
         //Update Location start
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
else if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Location Services are disabled please enable location services to enjoy nearby experience" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
    alert.tag = 103;
    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark CLLocationManager Delegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    //NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    //NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

     [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: I am using that function will it be called ?

Comment: Yeah, sure, but first you set the delegate & start updating location...

Comment: Yes but after I get the location once I am stopping to update. I am using the method didUpdateToLocations

Comment: Add this line [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your stuff in `applicationWillEnterForeground` because this method will get called when you come from setting `app to your app`.

You can write your code in this method like,

```
 if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
}
```